# How to create Avro schemas for a generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I'm working on developing an .NET Standard pub/sub package using Kafka and [Confluent's .NET client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).  My producer has the following interface.

**IEventPublisher.cs**

```
public interface IEventPublisher<T>
{
    bool Publish(Event<T> evnt);
}
```

My `KafkaEventPublisher<T>` class implements this interface and the payload, T, being published is wrapped in an `Event<T>` envelope.

**Event.cs**

```
public class Event<T>
{
    // Some other properties 

    public T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

The initial implementation of my component doesn't use the Avro serializer or the Schema Registry.  It serializes the `Event<T>` to JSON using `Newtonsoft.Json` and produces the string to a Kafka topic.  The up side to this is that the payload can be literally any object.  The topic name is the fully qualified class name of the object so a topic guaranteed to be homogeneous.  The downside is that the payloads are opaque to Kafka.

I'm now working on converting from `Newtonsoft.Json` to Avro and the Schema Registry.  This seems to indicate that my models can't be literally anything anymore.  They have to be specifically written to allow for Avro serialization by implementing the `ISpecificRecord` interface.  If this is true, it isn't ideal, but I can live with it.

The issue I can't seem to figure out is how to incorporate the `Event<T>` envelope into the Avro schemas.  Is there a way to nest a schema inside another schema?  Should all of my concrete schemas also define the `Event<T>` envelope?  Would it be wise to use `GenericRecord` instead and attempt to auto-generate the schema at runtime using reflection so my component can go back to accepting literally any object as a payload?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a more elegant way, but including the right thing in every schema should do the trick. Perhaps you want to do this programmatically to ensure consistency.

In general everything that works is probably fine, except if you find yourself trying to inspect every message and define the schema for each individual message. That may be possible but will certainly not be performant/desirable.